# Python's 'logging' to GCP's StackDriver connection issue

Tags: python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I can directly push log-entries to Stackdriver by 'google.cloud.logging'. Now, I am trying to connect Python's 'logging' to GCP's Stackdriver, to automatically create logs in Stackdriver whenever python's 'logging' is used. Connection part is where I am having trouble.

**I am getting this case:**

The entries get stored in Stackdriver temporarily, and can be fetched too, but they vanishes once program ends. It seems they get stored in buffer, but don't get persisted in Stackdriver logs.

**portion of code:**

```
    import google.cloud.logging as gcp_logging
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    cred= service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('credential/service/account/json/file')
    client = gcp_logging.Client(project = <project-id>, credentials=cred)

    import logging
    client.setup_logging(log_level=logging.DEBUG)   

    py_logger = get_python_logger()
    print("Making log entry here ...")
    py_logger.debug("log entry by lib 'logging' through Stackdriver in logger module")
```

**Executing code:**
Output is in 4 steps:

1. it fetched log-entries from Stackdriver
2. I tried to make log entry to Stackdriver through python's 'logging'
3. it fetches log-entries again
4. filtering fetched logs based on level

I expected new log-entry by Python's 'logging' to be fetched from Stackdriver. But, extra entries about oauth2 and http connection requests are being made. It seems like some authentication issue. I checked firewall rules in GCP, it allows all incoming ips.

`$python test.py`

```
    fetching log entries for logname: edudata-log ...  
    [2019-07-04 17:24:43.226848][WARNING] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:25:58.156544][WARNING] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:26:19.780465][WARNING] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:24.196522][INFO] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:35.216711][INFO] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:44.895962][DEBUG] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:58.220334][DEBUG] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 19:13:51.840192][INFO] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py

    Making log entry here ...
    log entry by lib 'logging' through Stackdriver in edulogger module

    fetching log entries for logname: edudata-log ...
    Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
    Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
    https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
    https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
    Submitted 1 logs
    Submitted 4 logs
    [2019-07-04 17:24:43.226848][WARNING] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:25:58.156544][WARNING] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:26:19.780465][WARNING] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:24.196522][INFO] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:35.216711][INFO] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:44.895962][DEBUG] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:58.220334][DEBUG] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 19:13:51.840192][INFO] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py

    filtering log entries for logname = <logname>, level = DEBUG ...
    Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token   
    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
    https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
    Submitted 1 logs
    Submitted 1 logs
    [2019-07-04 17:27:44.895962][DEBUG] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py
    [2019-07-04 17:27:58.220334][DEBUG] log entry through module edu_logger called in test_edulogger.py

    Waiting up to 5 seconds.
    Background thread exited gracefully.
    Sent all pending logs.
```

**Additional details:**
1. stackdriver is installed
2. I specified credentials here:
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH
3. I want logging's log ouput to be stored in GCP Stackdriver log

Comment: 1) Do you have Stackdriver installed on your instance? 2) You do not need to specify credentials when creating the client. 3) You are seeing extra output because you set the level to DEBUG. 4) Do you want your log output to be included with the GCP logging or as a new global log file that you specify? Edit your question with new details. Note: For GCP and Python, all you need to do is import the logging package and then log messages. Example: `import logging`, `logging.info('Hello logging world')`. Your log output will be included with the Stackdriver VM instance messages.

Comment: I have added additional details at bottom of post. I believe that there is some credential feed issue. I have seen two files: service account and oauth client secret.

This is not giving desired results:   
cred= service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('filepath')   
  
So, I have specified credential in env variable:
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH

Comment: Client Secrets are for User Account authentication, you cannot use them in place of a service account. As I said in my comment, you don't need to use a service account. Remove that code and clear the environment variable and use the Compute Engine Default service account.

Comment: @JohnHanley GCP Tutorial made it look so easy that I am jumped in directly. I have read some about api key, client OAuth client ID and service account key. I will try what you suggested.